# Order results of a SQL Server registered query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I order the results of a SQL Server query against registered servers?

I tried:

```
with cte as
(   select count(*) deprecatedCount
        from style
        where code in 
            (   'BYR'
                ,'GWP'
                ,'MRO'
                ,'STD'
                ,'VEF'
                ,'ZMK'
                ,'ZWR'
            )
)

select * from cte order by deprecatedCount
```

...but the deprecatedCount column remains unsorted.

(I don't have enough reputation to include "registered" in the tags list.)

Comment: You should also include an example of the output that you are currently seeing, and an example of how you expect the output to appear.  With the current query that you've shown in your question, there would only be a single row returned, so "sorting", in that context, doesn't make any sense.  Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: You're returning a single row, the count, so how are you expecting to sort one row?

Comment: if you want count by code, use "select code, count(*) as deprecatedCount"  and then "group by code" after the where statement

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the comments

```
with cte as
(   select code, count(*) deprecatedCount
        from style
        where code in 
            (   'BYR'
                ,'GWP'
                ,'MRO'
                ,'STD'
                ,'VEF'
                ,'ZMK'
                ,'ZWR'
            )
        group by code
)

select * from cte order by deprecatedCount
```